# How to read in only the first line of a text file?

Tags: c++, ifstream

The name of the text file that I want to open is "map.txt". I ONLY want to read in the first line of the file to the console. The first line of the text file is:

> E1    346    473   1085   3725   30   30

Here is the code I have so far.

```
ifstream file;

file.open("map.txt");

if (!file) //checks to see if file opens properly
{
    cerr << "Error: Could not find the requested file.";
}
    /******* loop or statement needed to read only first line here?**********/
```

Comment: Maybe you need a `getline()` instead of the `while()`

Comment: `std::string line; std::getline(file, line)`, though I admit I make no sense of "stop when done reading the file", since by your own description, you're done when you read the first line.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. I copied that part from another program that I used to read the entire file to the console. I will delete that now that you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like WhozCraig said in their comment, use `std::string` and `std::getline()`.

```
ifstream file;

file.open("map.txt");
string line;

if (!file) //checks to see if file opens properly
{
    cerr << "Error: Could not find the requested file.";
}
else
{
    if (getline(file, line)) cout << line; // Get and print the line.
    file.close(); // Remember to close the file.
}
```